# data being printed out twice when using fread

Tags: c, file-io, struct, fread

I am reading from a file using Binary File IO function **fread** When i run the program final entry is printed out twice

```
FILE *fp;
struct entry temp;
if (fp = fopen("recs.bin","rb"))
{
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        fread(&temp,sizeof (struct entry),1,fp);
        printf("%s  %s  %s \n", temp.name ,temp.design ,temp.contact);
    }
    fclose(fp);
else 
{
      printf("\error opening file\n");
}
```

When i run the code the output is as following

```
    Pfor.ABC    Professor    9867552
    Sir Blah    lecturar     9237434
    Miss etc    Asst. Porfessor     03847363      
    Miss etc    Asst. Porfessor     03847363
```

I always get the last entry twice 
I tried by printing beofre reading like below

```
while (!feof(fp))
{
        printf("%s  %s  %s \n", temp.name ,temp.design ,temp.contact);
        fread(&temp,sizeof (struct entry),1,fp);
}
```

now output is

```
    #gd^&!d     $!du(!      #$@%@22        //Some garbage values
    Pfor.ABC    Professor    9867552
    Sir Blah    lecturar     9237434
    Miss etc    Asst. Porfessor     03847363
```

Now the printing twice is solved but a garbage value is being printed 
I think its the problem in **feof(fp)** but cant figure it out

Comment: `printing beofre reading`.. how does that sound to yourself?? doensn't it sound `//Some garbage values` ??

Comment: Check return value of `fread`. It fails to read last entry, but `temp` still holds old data.

Comment: @Sourav i know but i was trying to figure out if it was being printed twice or read twice printing before reading made me clear that there is a problem in reading

Comment: @keltar then why !feof() not stopping it read further when file is ended

Comment: @SayamQazi because it checked after (failed) fread and printf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double handling of the last entry comes from using `feof`, which is [usually not a good way to control file Input loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Instead, you should check the return value of the reading functions `fgetc`, `fgets` and, in your case, `fread`. `fread` returns the number of items, i.e. the number of blocks of `size` bytes, read. If that is smaller than the number of items to read, you have an incomplete read. So:

```
while (fread(&temp, sizeof(struct entry), 1, fp) == 1) {
    printf("%s  %s  %s \n", temp.name, temp.design, temp.contact);
}
```

As long as you have a complete read, print out the data.

Others have already pointed out that printing the (uninitialised) data before reading it leads to your garbage values. If you must use such a set-up, you should at least place one read before the loop.